# How to fix [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/app/myProjectManager/settings.py/staticfiles/staticfiles.json' Django

Tags: python, django, web

I am trying to deploy an project manager app to heroku. It's running working locally. 
I am following the tutorial https://www.codementor.io/@jamesezechukwu/how-to-deploy-django-app-on-heroku-dtsee04d4 to deploy me app. I don't know where is the error and how to fix so hope you can help. 
`NotADirectoryError at /`, saying `[Errno 20] Not a directory: '/app/myProjectManager/settings.py/staticfiles/staticfiles.json'`

Here is some of my backend code:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/
PROJECT_ROOT   =   os.path.join(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT  =   os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Extra lookup directories for collectstatic to find static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
)

#  Add configuration for static files storage using whitenoise
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

import dj_database_url 
prod_db  =  dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(prod_db)
```

I cannot link to the static file successfully. 
This is the error part of my html template code: 
`Error during template rendering`

```
<link
    rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css"
    href="{% static 'projectManager/style.css' %}"
  />
```

My views.py:

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'projectManager/home.html', {'projects': Project.objects.all()})
```

My models.py:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=timezone.now())

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/app/myProjectManager/settings.py/staticfiles/staticfiles.json'

Culprit is:

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(__file__))
# That means:
#     PROJECT_ROOT = '/app/myProjectManager/settings.py/'
# And:
#     STATIC_ROOT: '/app/myProjectManager/settings.py/staticfiles/'
# which is incorrect
```

---

If `staticfiles` is inside `app`, then change it to:

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
# That means:
#     PROJECT_ROOT: '/app/'
# And:
#     STATIC_ROOT: '/app/staticfiles/'
# Which is correct.
```

---

**You need to update `PROJECT_ROOT` according to where your `settings.py` is located compared to the root directory of your project.**